# SSAS attribute relationships error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I am trying to establish attribute relationships on DimCustomer dimension of AdventureWorksDW database.
I have addded City,Country,StateProvince attributes. Then I have linked appropriate relationships between these attributes such as:

CustomerKey-->City-->StateProvince-->Country

When I try to deploy the solution I get an unknown error.I have queried the DimGeography database table to get the duplicate records:

```
select * from DimGeography where city like 'Bir%'

GeographyKey City                           StateProvinceCode StateProvinceName    
------------ ------------------------------ ----------------- --------------------
232          Birmingham                     ENG               England             
280          Birmingham                     AL                Alabama             

(2 row(s) affected)
```

So, there are duplicate keys. How can I solve this problem. Please help

Comment: I think maybe you haven't actually linked your relationships appropriately. Those two records have different id values.

Answer (score 0):

Yesss,
Finally I found the solutions after 2 hours googling!

Named Columns and Key columns mapping is the answer of the question. Key columns provide the uniqueness of the attribute.